# Finder don't save/remember new window default size

Tags: finder, high-sierra

I got an issue that's driving me crazy - I can't understand how to permanently change finder window default size.

I'm running Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13 (17A405) (latest stable).

When I'm open new window from Finder dock icon, resize it as I want to, close window, relaunch Finder all new windows I open this way (from dock icon or CMD + N) opens in new size, but if I open Finder another way (for example - by connecting to network share, or from Go in upper menu, or by creating a new folder and open it with double click) - all this windows open in another "default"size (not what I set).

When I open folder view settings (CMD + J) and all I have changed is window size button Use as default is greyed out (I have to change something else, for example - column wight)

Also I have tried (in every possible order with window size change & Use as default for view options):
deleting all ".DS_Store files"
deleting all Finder .plist's
many reboots, log off/login combination &
many Finder restarts
Some combinations with cmd & opt keys when resizing and closing Finder windows.

Also I created a new user, for test Finder window size behaviour for him - and behaviour is just like I write in upper text - the same.

I'm actually spent about two days for this experiments.

So, the question is - is this Mac OS X standard behaviour, and there is now way to change Finder default window size for all ways to open Finder without 3-rd party apps? Or I have something broken in my system, that prevents my Finder setting to save my changes?

Comment: Guys? Any ideas?

Comment: You're not alone. Same issue. So if it's broke then we're both broken the same way - I doubt that.

Comment: I see it's been a while since you posted - did you find the answer?

Comment: nope, no solution, no new answers, nothing